# Dashboard Graph Not Showing

Tags: magento2

Does anyone know why after upgrading to Magento 2.2.9, we don't see the Dashboard Graph?  It seems really obvious but I can't work it out and my searches on Google aren't helping :-(

Any help greatly appreciated

Mike

[image: Missing graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.2.9 uses Google Image Charts that is deprecated.
If you want to see charts, you must upgrade to 2.3.2 or 2.3.3 version.

This is a piece of 2.2.2 changelog:

> Google chart API updated to the Image-Charts. Magento now uses the
>   Image-Charts free service to render static charts in Admin dashboards.
>   Earlier deployments used Google Image Charts, which was deprecated in
>   2012 and turned off on March 18, 2019.

More details here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.2OpenSource.html

Comment: Thank you - I knew it would be obvious - can't see the wood for trees.